# Cannot compile ffmpeg with fdk-aac

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to compile ffmpeg with libfdk-aac on Ubuntu 13.04. I followed the following instructions to compile libfdk-aac
`wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/opencore-amr/fdk-aac-0.1.0.tar.gz

tar xzvf fdk-aac-0.1.0.tar.gz

cd fdk-aac-0.1.0

./configure

make

sudo checkinstall --pkgname=fdk-aac --pkgversion="0.1.0" --backup=no
  --deldoc=yes \
 --fstrans=no --default

ldconfig`

I followed the following instructions to compile ffmpeg
`git clone --depth 1 git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg

cd ffmpeg

./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb \

   --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis \

   --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libaacplus \

   --enable-x11grab --enable-libfdk-aac

make

sudo checkinstall --pkgname=ffmpeg --pkgversion="5:$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --backup=no \

  --deldoc=yes --fstrans=no --default

hash x264 ffmpeg ffplay ffprobe`

**Problem**
While compiling FFmpeg, in the ./configure line, it fails with the error:
`ERROR: libfdk_aac not found`
The last lines of config.log are:

> gcc -Wl,--as-needed -o /tmp/ffconf.w9wba0C3 /tmp/ffconf.Fw03YJzI.o -lfdk-aac -lfaac -laacplus -lm -pthread -lz
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `ceil'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `atan2'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `acos'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `sin'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `atan'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `exp'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `tan'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `cos'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `log'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `pow'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `sqrt'
> /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.so: undefined reference to `floor'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ERROR: libfdk_aac not found

All the other libraries were installed. It works fine without `--enable-libfdk-aac` flag. I just heard that fdk-aac is the best AAC encoder, so I wanted to install that with FFmpeg if possible.
PS: The exact steps I followed for the whole process is in https://gist.github.com/abhi92/5711831. I installed every library in that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That guide is a copy of the one from here & also doesn't reflect some changes that were recently made. The changes came from discussions we had about installing static libs & includes to /usr/local & the potential issues that doing so may cause.

I personally use /opt/ffmpeg_current instead of $HOME/ffmpeg_build but that is just personal choice, the theory & better install practice is the same.

So I suggest you remove all from that gisthub nonsense & follow this link, all should go fine

https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

Note - I guess my sugges about the man pages didn't get done. I'd add this to ffmpeg ./configure (may as well add a datadir too.

```
--mandir=/usr/local/share/man --datadir=/usr/local/share/ffmpeg
```

Comment: (Bump). The man pages are not working though. Minor annoyance, would be glad if it can be fixed??  

`man: can't resolve /usr/local/share/man/man1/ffmpeg.1.gz: No such file or directory`

Also, is the git master stable enough for production use?

Comment: as far as man pages see edit/note to answer.

Comment: Any way to add the man pages without rebuilding?

Comment: Not really though it you produced them then I guess you could copy to a man1 dir in /usr/local/share/man or /usr/share/man & may work from terminal. (by copy I mean the *.1.gz files, not the .texi files in source. You may find reading them easier online then in terminal - http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html ( I use the manpage scope in 13.04 & 12.04, much better than terminal

Comment: Yeah it is easier to read them online. That's what I've been doing.    Not a fan of unity, so no scope for me.